# how to get user Input between 2 lines

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
printf(" What is your guess:");
printf("         (hint:don't guess %d)",half);
scanf("%d", &guess);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean here? Please explain what you want to see.

Comment: If you mean you want the cursor to appear after the word `guess`, you don't with <stdio.h> functions.  You would need something more advanced like ncurses.

Comment: Using `printf("         (hint:don't guess %d)\r         (spaces)             ",half); fflush(stdout);` might work  (note \r), but not portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with *Standard C* (with `stdio.h`), so I would re-arranging your code, like this:

```
printf("What is your guess (hint: don't guess %d): ", half);
scanf("%d", &guess);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `wherex()` and `wherey()` to get the current x and y coordinate of the cursor. Then move the cursor with `gotoxy`

- Print text
- get current x and y position of cursor and save them `wherex()` and `wherey()`
- move cursor more to the right `gotoxy()`
- print 2nd text
- move cursor back to the position you saved `gotoxy()`

You will find the functions in `conio.h`. It is only available under Windows.

http://code-reference.com/c/conio.h/gotoxy
http://code-reference.com/c/conio.h/wherex
http://code-reference.com/c/conio.h/wherey

Comment: You should mention that Conio is generally only available on Windows, not Unix/Linux.

Comment: @Barmar that's true, but i can't edit my answer without removing the links again. it's telling me that it's unformatted code... tried to use the option to add hyperlinks but it still tells me it's code ...

Answer (score 0):

Try backspaces

```
printf("What is your guess:           (hint: don't guess %d)", half);
printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
fflush(stdout);
if (scanf("%d", &guess) != 1) /* error */;
```

You will need to tweak the number of backspaces printed. And take into account the size of `half`.

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all write the second output to a string:

```
size_t size = strlen("         (hint:don't guess )") + 6 // for numbers with < 6 digits
char *temp = malloc(size); // Alocate enough space
snprintf(temp, size, "         (hint:don't guess %d)", YOUR_NUMBER); // Write to string
```

Then, get the length of your final string:

```
size_t len = strlen(temp);
```

Now, write the string to the terminal:

```
print("%s", temp);
```

After this, you need to move the cursor back. `'\b'` moves the cursor back by one character. So you need a little loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    putchar('\b');
```

And your cursor will be there where you started.

Note: If you need to go back to the beginning of the line, you can simple use `'\r'`.